# How to change data format returned from a MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

So, I'm working in Laravel and I have the following API GET route that returns a query from my DB with documents and their categories:

```
Route::get('documents', function() {
return DB::table('documents')
->join('documents_categories','documents_categories.documentCategoryID','=','documents.documentCategoryID')
->select('documentName','documentCategoryName')
->get(); });
```

Which returns all my documents sorted by their category:

```
{documentName: "Certificación de Licencia", documentCategoryName: "Aeronáutica Civil"}

{documentName: "Horas de Vuelo", documentCategoryName: "Aeronáutica Civil"}

{documentName: "Antecedente Penal", documentCategoryName: "Antecedentes"}

{documentName: "Traslado de Animales y Plantas", documentCategoryName: "Certificado de Sanidad Animal o Vegetal"}

{documentName: "Calidad y Apto para el Consumo Humano", documentCategoryName: "Certificados Comerciales"}

{documentName: "Certificado de Libre Venta", documentCategoryName: "Certificados Comerciales"}

{documentName: "Certificado de Origen", documentCategoryName: "Certificados Comerciales"}

{documentName: "Patente", documentCategoryName: "Certificados Comerciales"}

{documentName: "Registro de Producto", documentCategoryName: "Certificados Comerciales"}

{documentName: "Signos Distintivos", documentCategoryName: "Certificados Comerciales"}
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to return the documents categories as JSON keys with the corresponding documents inside an array. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Civiles":["document1","document2"],
        "Antecedentes":["document1","document2"]
    }
]
```

What's the best way to get it done?
Thanks you all for the help!

Comment: Himad, what have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Laravel >=5.3 then your query will return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)

You can use a mixture of [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby), [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) and [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck):

```
Route::get('documents', function () {
    return DB::table('documents')
        ->join('documents_categories', 'documents_categories.documentCategoryID', '=', 'documents.documentCategoryID')
        ->select('documentName', 'documentCategoryName')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('documentCategoryName')
        ->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->pluck('documentName');
        });
});
```

If you're using Laravel 5.4 you can take this one step further and use [Higher Order Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#higher-order-messages) by changing:

```
->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->pluck('documentName');
});
```

to:

```
->map->pluck('documentName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I mistaken your question. My bad. Thanks @Rafael

**Edited Version :**

Well you can use the collect method of Laravel on `$documentList`

```
$namelist = collect($documentList)->groupBy('documentCategoryName');
```

It's going to return something like this. Not in json format. It would be in array format.

```
$namelist = {
    category1: [
        {
            documentName: "d1",
            documentCategoryName: "category1"
        },
        {
            documentName: "D2",
            documentCategoryName: "category1"
        }
    ],
}
```

Well after that you can traverse this array

```
$res = array();
foreach ($namelist as $key => $value){
    array_push($res[$key], $value['documentname']);
}
```

And return `$res`. It would be your desired output.

Let the know if you looking for something like this.

Comment: This is not really what he asked @Amku91. The response is already coming as a json, according to him.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion. Now it's look what he looking for.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Laravel docs for [`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby) on the collection class.

Since `get()` returns a collection, you can chain this method on the end.

```
Route::get('documents', function() {
    return DB::table('documents')
        ->join('documents_categories','documents_categories.documentCategoryID','=','documents.documentCategoryID')
        ->select('documentName','documentCategoryName')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('documentCategoryName');
});
```